# Dimensions of visible area in an svg

Tags: javascript, svg, viewbox

How would one go about finding the maximum and minimum x & y values in an svg, in the presence of a viewbox that is. The issue that occurs is that I am attempting to create a partially transparent rect overlay. However, the different versions of android spew out wonderfully inconsistent differences between container widths. Rephrasing the question for clarity how would one find the visible coordinates of an svg where the coordinates lie outside the viewbox, but the aspect ratio has been preserved?